# Add calculated column from different tables usin ef core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.1

I want to calculate column value if another column in a related table changes.

`Product` class:

```
public class Product
{
    private int totalQuantity;

    private bool quantityAlert;

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int MinimumQuantity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual List<StockProduct> StockProducts { get; set; }

    public int TotalQuantity
    {
        get
        {
            return totalQuantity;
        }
        protected set
        {
            int q = 0;

            foreach (var product in StockProducts)
            {
                q += product.Quantity;
            }
            totalQuantity = q;
        }
    }

    public bool QuantityAlert
    {
        get { return quantityAlert; }
        protected set
        { 
            quantityAlert = TotalQuantity <= MinimumQuantity; 
        }
    }
}
```

`StockProduct` class:

```
public class StockProduct
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid StockProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double BuyingPrice { get; set; }
    public double SellingPrice { get; set; }
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

`appContext` configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .Property(p => p.TotalQuantity)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
    .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property);

modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .Property(p => p.QuantityAlert)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
    .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property);
```

Error message is

> SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: Products.TotalQuantity'.

If I set default value for total quantity and minimum quantity, I get the same error, but if default for `QuantityAlert` is set to false, it stays false even if the default total quantity = 0 is less than the default minimum quantity = 0.

Not according to

```
quantityAlert = TotalQuantity <= MinimumQuantity;
```

Comment: Do you have  TotalQuantity and QuantityAlert columns in your DB?

Comment: it crashes on DB intialization and shows above error but, the two columns will be created on setting their default values

Comment: Yes , since you included ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate  you should assign default values of your column. But you should remove ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate   from your context  if you want EF to count sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Entity Framework Core Fluent API ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate provides a way to indicate that the value for the selected property will be generated whenever a new entity is added to the database or an existing one is modified. Therefore the property should not be included in INSERT or UPDATE statements when SQL is generated by EF Core. It means that it has a default column value in your db or it will be generated by a trigger. As I guess you don't have any of these so you have to remove ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate  from you DB context. And change your TotalQuantity and QuantityAlert properties

```
 public int TotalQuantity
    {
        get { return  StockProducts==null? 0: StockProducts.Sum(p=>p.Quantity; }
        protected set {}
}
    }
public bool QuantityAlert
    {
        
         get {return   quantityAlert = TotalQuantity <= MinimumQuantity; }
       protected set {}
}
    }
```

And don't forget to include StockProducts in your any select Product query.